# Deleting rows from group_concat query with list shorter than X words

Tags: mysql, where-clause, sql-like, group-concat

I want to select Rows from a column     **Team** from the table     **Employees**

The fields in Teams consists of combinations of 3-5 predetermined names in the format John,Mike,Peter,Robert,Stanley

How do I select rows only in which **Team** has 5 or more names in the field?

e.g. if the column contained two rows of teams:

```
    Mike,Peter,John                 
    John,Mike,Peter,Robert,Stanley
```

only the second row would be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the occurrence of Comma and then fetch record by putting where  clause count >=5

Now ,There is no built-in function that counts occurrences of sub-string in a string, but you can calculate the difference between the original string, and the same string without commas:

```
Comma Count = LENGTH(Full Text) - LENGTH(REPLACE(Full Text, ',', ''))
```